# Difficulty to connect a blogspot blog to a custom domain

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy, cname, blogspot

I have a blog on Google BlogSpot service for many years, and purchased a custom domain using Blogger's own domain service several years back. It was working fine and I was annually renewing it. Google lately introduced Google Workspace for domains, so, I wanted to transfer the domain to GoDaddy. I transferred it but now, I am unable to connect to it.

I added the same custom domain under Blogger settings, and switched redirect button. But the custom domain takes us to a 'This domain is parked page' on GoDaddy. I contacted GoDaddy, they asked me for DNS records from Google. When I logged in to the custom domain dashboard, they do not have the DNS records of my custom domain.

Is this something you are familiar with?